Mutt hides full headers and i cannot see how to get full header information for emails
i am running what seems to be Mutt 1.9.4 (2018-02-28). And the problem is that I cannot obtain full header information for incoming emails. the h just provides an additional Mime-Version: 1.0 and messageID (if it includes cc participants).
I have tried to play around with the muttrc configurations, but none of the obvious things works. any ideas?

You didn't give any details as to what headers you are seeing when weeding is on, maybe you're already seeing most of them?  Or details of what headers you expect that are missing... so I didn't address specific headers.

I take it you're accessing IMAP folders rather than local mboxes or maildirs. Then see the $imap-headers variable in the manual:

3.140. imap_headers
Type: string
Default: (empty)
Mutt requests these header fields in addition to the default headers (“Date:”, “From:”, “Sender:”, “Subject:”, “To:”, “Cc:”, “Message-Id:”, “References:”, “Content-Type:”, “Content-Description:”, “In-Reply-To:”, “Reply-To:”, “Lines:”, “List-Post:”, “X-Label:”) from IMAP servers before displaying the index menu. You may want to add more headers for spam detection.
Note: This is a space separated list, items should be uppercase and not contain the colon, e.g. “X-BOGOSITY X-SPAM-STATUS” for the “X-Bogosity:” and “X-Spam-Status:” header fields.

You need to specify which headers you want mutt to retrieve from the IMAP server in addition to the ones it does by default.
As an alternative to having mutt access mails over the IMAP protocol, you can use things like offlineimap to synchronise your email into local maildir folders, and then you'll be able to access the contents instantly including all the headers and use your favourite mail indexer for searching emails.

You can check the mutt manual (zcat  /usr/share/doc/mutt/manual.txt.gz  | less on most systems) for exact details, but header weeding docs are kinda scattered through the whole document with a few cross references for options to change when and what is weeded and where the keybinding works (almost everywhere).
In the default configuration the h key is bound to "display-toggle-weed" which will toggle weeding headers.  This has been the case as long as I can remember, possibly version 1.0.
Looking through the manual, as far as I can tell, this is an all or nothing option.  Either it does or does not weed headers. I would say that toggling this changes your message at all, then you are seeing the full headers in the message.  Maybe the message was saved in the mailbox with most of the headers were already stripped out?  This could also happen if this is a locally transported message and your local MTA doesn't add a lot of headers.
The alternatives would be that you have changed your pager to an external pager, or the keybinding has been changed, but then you shouldn't see any changes when you press h.
If your mailbox is in a flat file, you can verify this by viewing the first message in the raw mailbox with something like less and compare that to what mutt displays.
